# Apache solr error while connecting with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, apache, solr

My intention is to connect mongodb with solr. 
During the time of core creation. I dont know how to create a solrconfig.xml.
please help me to create that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't - mongo connections aren't configured like that.

Instead you have to use [something like `mongo-connector`](https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector).

It'll act as a piece between your mongo collection as a replication destination, inserting updated data into your Solr collection as the mongo collection changes.

> `mongo-connector` creates a pipeline from a MongoDB cluster to one or more target systems, such as Solr, Elasticsearch, or another MongoDB cluster. It synchronizes data in MongoDB to the target then tails the MongoDB oplog, keeping up with operations in MongoDB in real-time.